# Angular JS - Page flickering without css

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngcloak

In my web application we have a master index.html , which includes header.html,footer.html,preference.html... and main view content .
When the page loads,(url = index.html#) I could see the static content of header,footer and then actual page loads in the screen.

Header.html,footer.html,preference.html requires css path  which is fetched from the db through a rest call. Flickering is due to non availability of the css path .
Is there a way to suppress the flickering problem ?
I have used ng-cloak and its not working as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Das .

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write some css in separated file to hide all your content. And some css to redefine styles in your main css. So all content will be hidden while main css is not loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-href with combination of ng-cloak

Also add this to your style tag

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: do i replace ng-include-ng-href  with ng-cloak ?

Comment: how are you including your css in your html, can you show that?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="yourLink" ng-cloak>

Comment: <link rel="{{stylesheet}}"  rel="stylesheet">. We have 3 different style sheets like this and the path will be resolved by a rest api call. Thanks